# htaccess в двух сайтах

Tags: php, html, mysql, .htaccess

знатаки. Есть проблема с сайтами, два сайта в одному выходит, один основной и второй залит в папку в нём же, но проблема состоит в том, что htaccess второго сайта который в папку, а не корень залит - не работает. Есть ли варианты решения данной проблемы или как-то прописать всё в основному htaccess?

Comment: `AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php`

Comment: *htaccess второго сайта

Comment: `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>



# END WordPress`
Первого сайта